# C header file not found when Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I would like to use this [language C code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/uclibc-ng/v1.0.8/source/libc/sysdeps/linux/common/ftruncate64.c) in Android by NDK. Data types `__off_t` and `__off64_t` are defined in [bits/types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/uclibc-ng/v1.0.8/source/libc/sysdeps/linux/common/bits/types.h), but I am getting: `fatal error: 'bits/types.h' file not found` while building app.

I can make a binary a run C program on Ubuntu without any problems but in Android there is problem with `include`.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <bits/types.h> <------- not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers starting with underscores and the contents of the `bits` directory are not guaranteed to be portable.

Android has a definition for `off64_t` and `off_t` (no underscores)  in the `<sys/types.h>` header.

So you should be able to do:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
typedef off64_t __off64_t;
typedef off_t __off_t;
```

... or just rename the types in the code you are trying to port.

... or you can use the the `ftruncate64` call that android ships in `<unistd.h>`?